# Load external pages through iframes

Tags: html, iframe

I am trying to load a webpage inside an iframe but all times I am getting the same error:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /test/app/www.google.com was not found on this server.

Apache/2.2.17 (Ubuntu) Server at lira.tlmat.unican.es Port 80
```

I am sending the url to my page in parameters (mypage.html?page=www.google.com)

But it always try to open a webpage inside my server. I want to load an external page.

This is the error I get:

```
GET http://myserver.es/test/app/www.google.com 404 (Not Found) newsPage.html?page=www.google.com:57
(anonymous function) newsPage.html?page=www.google.com:57
c jquery-1.9.1.min.js:3
p.fireWith jquery-1.9.1.min.js:3
b.extend.ready jquery-1.9.1.min.js:3
H
```

Comment: Probably server error, not code error at first instance. Please upload code so someone can help.

Comment: I added the error I get

Comment: Please add `http://` before www.google.com

Comment: It works. I just have problem with same origin domain now. But I think it is imposible to solve it using iframes. Do you know a way to do it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy

Comment: This solved the problem about same origin. I used one of the solutions in that link. Thank you so much. I will save the link for future references

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need "http://" at the start of the URL in your iframe, to indicate it is an external URL. Could you try appending "http://" to the page GET parameter?